# Why "moved on" is used in "Maybe it's time we all moved on"?

Tags: grammar

In Friends series, season 10 episode 2, at minute 22:20, Ross tells Joey

> "Well then, maybe it's time we all moved on".

Why he says "moved on" and not "move on"?

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible.

*Moved* makes it counterfactual (in the same way as "if we moved on") - it implies "we haven't moved/aren't moving on, but what about if we did!"

*Move* is not counterfactual - it is not saying anything about whether or not we are already moving on.

Because these are both really about the future, the difference in meaning is slight.

Comment: Thank you. Is it used in formal written English as well or it's just spoken English?

Comment: I'm not sure what the _it_ is in your question, but both these forms are standard parts of the language, used in speech and writing.

Comment: @R.Javid It's time is always followed by a past simple in this context, it's kind of a fixed structure or idiom! https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/it-s-time

Comment: @Cardinal: I agree that the past is much more likely here, and I agree with the   Cambridge Dictionary that "It's time we go home" doesn't work. But I don't find anything odd about "Maybe it's time we all move on". I think it's the "maybe" that makes a difference, but I'm not sure.